# MIgrate from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 without reporting services backup

Tags: tfs

I am planning my migration from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013.  I am using the guide at http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/755804#

Currently my TFS 2010 server has a reporting services instance installed with the required databases:

- Tfs_Warehouse
- Tfs_Analysis
- ReportServer
- ReportServerTempDb

Can I migrate to a new TFS 2013 server without backing up / restoring the reporting services?  Basically not installing reporting services and then just later on installing a new instance of reporting services?

Will this work or will the migration process fail?  Will I lose any functionality if I do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch over to a new instance of reporting services without backing up the database and the encryption key from the old one, you'll lose any custom/modified reports, as well as have to re-apply security settings. Other than that, there's no harm in it.

The warehouse and analysis databases are not part of reporting services, they're the TFS warehouse and analysis cube databases. They're created by TFS.

The ReportServer database is the one that holds all your reports.

Comment: Currently the server is only being used for source control so I feel like nothing would be lost.  I just really don't want the migration to fail.  Quick question: Is it possible to install native mode and SharePoint integrated mode on the same instance? The TFS databases will be on a SharePoint instance

Comment: Nope it wont fail , go ahead and restore the other Tfs_* databases other than the reporting ones , I have done it, It worked.